# Bootstrap dropdown menu keeps getting stuck on the top left of the screen and it won't move

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

So I'm building a Deezer clone(sort of) and in it I'm trying to use a dropdown menu but it is stuck on the top left of the body. even though i tried changing the margin(all ways), position absolute (with top and all ) and nothing worked. please help !

the drop menu html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/frame2.css"> 
</head>  
<body>  
      <div class="slide">
        <img class="search_icon" src="images/icons8-chercher-30.png" height="50" width="50">
        <input  class="search" type="text"  placeholder="Search">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">+
          </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-utilisateur-32.png" class="admin" >
          </a> 
      </div>
 </body>  
</html
```

The CSS code :

```
/* frame2 */

.search{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1105px;
    height: 58px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 5px;
    
    border-style: none;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    
   }
   ::placeholder {
    color: #BEBEBE;
    }
    .search_icon{
        position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .plus{
        position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 1160px;
    font-size: 200 px;
    }
    .admin{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 1200px;
    }

.dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    left: 800;
}
```

[The output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RsES.png)

Comment: Want to clarify, you want to whole dropdown(including + button) move from left to 800px?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position:absolute` if its not necessary. In your case, you are positioning all elements. If you are trying to make inline all elements in `slide` class. Use `flex` or `grid`. I've a little updated your code, but the changes are tiny. Advicing you to learn html coding from youtube or have a courses. Also if you are already included `bootstrap` to your webpage, then use it =) Also you may find many tutorials of bootstrap in youtube.

Related to your question. You are trying to move `dropdown-menu`(this is a inner element of whole dropdown section), its already attached to parent dropdown element. thus the position changes wont work. You need to apply positional changes to `.dropdown` itself.

But I've already edited your code using `flex`, so here is the code, CSS:

```
/* frame2 */

.search{
    //position: absolute;
    width: 1105px;
    height: 58px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 5px;
    
    border-style: none;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    
   }
   ::placeholder {
    color: #BEBEBE;
    }
    .search_icon{
     //   position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .plus{
    //    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 1160px;
    font-size: 200 px;
    }
    .admin{
    //position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    }
.slide {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown {
    width: 100px;
}
```

It's not perfect, but it works. Again, i would do other way. Here is the bootstrap 4 cheat sheet if you need to learn bootstrap https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/